# Displaying String/Label in JavaFX

Tags: java, string, javafx, label

I need help figouring out simply how to display a text in my program so that it can display "Stop" in the middle of my polygon shape I've created. What I'm trying to do is create a stop sign. I have already taken care of creating and displaying that stop sign, so now I just need to display "Stop" in t

```
package application;
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    pane.getChildren().add(polygon);
    polygon.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED); //sets the color of polygon
    ObservableList<Double> list = polygon.getPoints();

    //create a label to display in the middle of the "stop sign" polygon shape
    //This is what I need most help on
    Label sign = new Label("Stop"); 
    sign.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    System.out.print(sign);

    final double WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 200;
    double centerX = WIDTH / 2, centerY = HEIGHT / 2;
    double radius = Math.min(WIDTH, HEIGHT) * 0.4;

    // Add points to the polygon list
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        list.add(centerX + radius * Math.cos(2 * i * Math.PI / 6));
        list.add(centerY - radius * Math.sin(2 * i * Math.PI / 6));
    }

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setTitle("ShowPolygon"); //Set the stage title 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); //Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); //Display the stage



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `Pane` with `StackPane` and add `sign` to it (after the polygon):

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED); //sets the color of polygon
    ObservableList<Double> list = polygon.getPoints();

    //create a label to display in the middle of the "stop sign" polygon shape
    //This is what I need most help on
    Label sign = new Label("STOP");
    //sign.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white; -fx-font-size: 3em");
    sign.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    System.out.print(sign);


    pane.getChildren().add(polygon);
    pane.getChildren().add(sign);

    final double WIDTH = 200, HEIGHT = 200;
    double centerX = WIDTH / 2, centerY = HEIGHT / 2;
    double radius = Math.min(WIDTH, HEIGHT) * 0.4;

    // Add points to the polygon list
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        list.add(centerX + radius * Math.cos(2 * i * Math.PI / 6));
        list.add(centerY - radius * Math.sin(2 * i * Math.PI / 6));
    }

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setTitle("ShowPolygon"); //Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); //Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); //Display the stage


}
```

Javadoc about the `StackPane`:

> StackPane lays out its children in a back-to-front stack. The z-order
>   of the children is defined by the order of the children list with the
>   0th child being the bottom and last child on top. If a border and/or
>   padding have been set, the children will be layed out within those
>   insets.
>
> The stackpane will attempt to resize each child to fill its content
>   area. If the child could not be sized to fill the stackpane (either
>   because it was not resizable or its max size prevented it) then it
>   will be aligned within the area using the alignment property, which
>   defaults to Pos.CENTER.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `new Pane()` to `new StackPane()` and add your label to the pane's child list like you do your Polygon.

[StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) is a layout manager that allows you to layer items on top of each other (by default centering the layered items).